# Netstandard.Library 1.6.1 blocked by project

Tags: visual-studio-2017, .net-core, .net-standard

I've created a brand new solution and project in VS2017 RC and for some reason I can't use the latest version of the NETStandard.Library package.

There's no code in the project and it's the first project in the solution.

When in the NuGet package manager it's listed in the dropdown, but marked as blocked by project.

Any ideas?

Comment: I think you need to have latest version VS2017 RC. Refer [this](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/15456/net-core-class-library-doesnt-resolve-netstandardl-9.html)

Comment: What kind of project did you create? Don't assume everyone can see your desktop.

Comment: Duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42320021/vs-2017-rc-i-can-not-update-netstandard-library-in-nuget

Comment: I have the RTW and still get this nonsense when creating a new project.

Answer (score 7):

You need to execute the command in Package manager console for your project
Install-Package NETStandard.Library

Comment: In the released version of VS 2017, the reference is no longer meant to be edited via NuGet. There is a property in the csproj that can override the version used - which is set when migrating from project.json.

Answer (score 7):

The `NETStandard.Library` package is no longer meant to be upgradable through the package management UI. The "SDK" component of the project emits this reference automatically and marked read-only.

This behaviour can be overridden through a property in the `csproj` file:

```
<NetStandardImplicitPackageVersion>1.6.1</NetStandardImplicitPackageVersion>
```

If you delete a line like this from your csproj file, you'll get the newest version that VS or the CLI knows about.

This property is usually added when migrating from `project.json` to `csproj`.  In this case, you can safely remove it.